# First select in php loop ending to soon

Tags: php, ajax

Not sure why but the loop I made outputs every select but the first one correctly. It looks like the loop ends early the first time around shows . 
   [loop ending early](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KlbGR.png) The loop gets its information from the first select 1: . then does an ajax call to the 2: php page where it sets $days to the first selects option value. Then the loop outputs two more selects until it equals the $days will be .
[The output showing the other selects working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbqN8.png)

1: First select

```
 <form>
      <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">How many days?</label>
    <select class="form-control" name="days" onchange="Selectdays(this.value);" id="exampleFormControlSelect1" required>
            <option>How many days?</option>
      <option value="1">1 day</option>
      <option value="2">2 days</option>
      <option value="3">3 days</option>
      <option value="4">4 days</option>
      <option value="5">5 days</option>
      <option value="6">6 days</option>
      <option value="7">7 days</option>
      <option value="8">8 days</option>
      <option value="9">9 days</option>      
      <option value="10">10 days</option>
    </select>
  </div>
<div id="days"></div>
```

2: Second Selects inside of the loop

```
$count = 0;
echo "<select class='form-control' name='select' id='exampleFormControlSelect1'> ";
while($count != $days) {
    echo "  
     <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='exampleFormControlSelect1'>Date</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='date' id='exampleFormControlSelect1'>
      <option>05/24/2018</option>
      <option>06/2/2018</option>
      <option>07/25/2019</option>
      <option>01/15/2017</option>
      <option>11/5/2018</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class='form-group'>
    <label for='exampleFormControlSelect1'>Hours</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='time' id='exampleFormControlSelect1' required>
      <option value=''>How many hours?</option>
      <option>1 hour</option>
      <option>2 hours</option>
      <option>3 hours</option>
      <option>4 hours</option>
      <option>5 hours</option>
      <option>6 hours</option>
      <option>7 hours</option>
      <option>8 hours</option>
    </select>
  </div>";
  $count++;
}
```

Comment: remove "echo "<select class='form-control' name='select' id='exampleFormControlSelect1'> ";" from outside while loop

Comment: @Jaydp I didn't notice that was there, but that fixed it.